# TeXStudio dependancy issues - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, qt, latex, texstudio

I was trying to install tex studio using

```
sudo apt install texstudio
```

But some dependencies are missing here. I understand that they are primarily the Qt libraries. I tried to install from qt website but couldn't solve the issues. But when I try to add libraries one by one, it also gives me same error that library depends on other libraries.

```
deca28@deca28-Inspiron-5575:~$ sudo apt install texstudio
[sudo] password for deca28:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texstudio : Depends: Libpoppler-qt5-1 (>= 0.81.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt5concurrent5 (>= 5.6.0~rc) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not going to be installed or
                      libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.11.0~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt5script5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqt5svg5 (>= 5.6.0~beta) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: Libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.12.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: Libqt5xml5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqtermwidget5-0 (>= 0.9.0~) but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: texlive-latex-base but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: texlive-latex-extra but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: texlive-latex-recommended but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: texlive-base but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: latex-beamer but it is not installable
             Recommends: dvipng but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
deca28@deca28-Inspiron-5575:~$
```

Any help for installing texstudio?

Comment: `apt` will resolve all dependencies automatically, **if** they are available in the distro & release you are trying to install from.  You should **not** break your system by installing libs directly from upstream - the packages are listed as dependencies so they **must** exist. What distro are you using?  What version?   Is it in the middle of a major transition from one state to another right now? (e.g. debian just made a new stable release so lots of new packages are flooding into unstable and trickling into testing.  This will cause some havoc until things settle down in a week or so)

Comment: Otherwise, this kind of problem can be caused if you have some held packages - that can prevent other packages (that conflict with, or depend on a newer version of, the held pkg) to be uninstallable.  That seems to be the case from the final line of the error message.  Try `dpkg -l '*' | grep '^h'` to see a list of held packages on your system.   You can unhold them with `apt-mark unhold`

Comment: `apt` will let you install multiple packages simultaneously, Specify them all on the same command. `sudo apt install texstudio Libpoppler-qt5-1 libqt5concurrent5 ...`. Read `man apt`.